# How do you make "Class" type safe in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, class, oop

I need to write a method that returns a class.

```
@implementation MyFactory

- (Class)defaultViewClass {
  return [MyView class];
}

@end
```

The returned class is not type safe. You can cast it to any random class. You can also call any random initializer method without a compiler error.

```
MyFactory *factory = [MyFactory new];
Class viewClass = [factory defaultViewClass];
RandomView *view = [[viewClass alloc] initWithRandomStuff];
```

How do I redefine my method to return a Class of a particular type? I want to do something like this, but the compiler complains that it can't return specific class types.

```
- (AbstractViewClass)defaultViewClass {
    return [ConcreteViewClass class];
}
```

The reason why I need to deal with classes rather than object pointers is because I need to call a static function polymorphically.

Comment: And you're providing this to someone else so you don't want to cast? Have you looked at protocols?

Comment: What you're trying to do (return a Class type that is restricted to a specific class and/or its subclasses) is not possible in Objective-C.  However, it is possible in Swift, and I can provide example code if you are interested.

Comment: @titaniumdecoy Sure, you can provide the Swift version. And is there a computer science term for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I'd also be interested in the Swift version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't get the benefit of compile-time type checking when working with Class objects in Objective-C due to the dynamic nature of the language.  However, you can enforce such constraints in a strictly typed language like Swift.

```
protocol AbstractView {
    init(parameter: Int)
}

class ConcreteView: AbstractView {
    required init(parameter: Int) { }
}

class ViewFactory {
    func defaultViewClass() -> AbstractView.Type {
        return ConcreteView.self
    }
}

let factory = ViewFactory()
let viewClass = factory.defaultViewClass()
let view = viewClass.init(parameter: 0)

print("\(view.self)", terminator: "") // Prints "ConcreteView"
```

AbstractView is a protocol as there is no concept of an abstract class in Swift, although it could just as easily be a class.